# Best way to add custom information to for logging

Tags: python, logging

I've been reading the Python [logging](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/logging.html) documentation, and its certainly has a lot of functionality...for everything.

The problem I'm facing is that I'm not Dutch and so I'm not sure what the right way to do this is.

I am running events in a simulator, and I would like to prefix every log message with the timestamp of the *simulated* time (probably with a length formatter too, just to keep it looking good). I could change this in a subclass of `Logger` or `Handler`, but I don't think that is the right way.

I think the right way is to use a `LoggerAdapter` or a `Filter`. Is this right, and if so, which one should I prefer?

Comment: I updated my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely if you just need to prefix every log message with the timestamp, all you need to do is provide an appropriate format string for a formatter? As mentioned [here](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#displaying-the-date-time-in-messages) in the documentation.

**Update:** A `LoggerAdapter` would be more appropriate for situations where contextual information is moderately long-lived. For example, in a network server application which handles multiple client connections, the connection details (e.g. client IP address) might be useful context, so you would create a `LoggerAdapter` instance when a new client connection was created. This doesn't sound like your simulation scenario.

A `Filter`, on the other hand, could be used if you could use it to get the simulation time, e.g.

```
class SimulationFilter(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self, context):
        """
        Set up with context passed in which allows access
        to simulation times.
        """
        self.context = context

    def filter(self, record):
        "Add sim_time field to record, formatted as you wish"
        record.sim_time = '%s' % self.context.get_sim_time()
        return True
```

and then add `%(sim_time)s` in your `Formatter`'s format string.

Alternatively, if you know the simulation time whenever you make a logging call, you could just do e.g.

```
logger.debug('Message with %s', arguments, extra={'sim_time': sim_time})
```

and likewise have `%(sim_time)s` in your `Formatter`'s format string.

Comment: I clarified that it is the *simulated* time that I want to include. Sorry for ambiguity.