# Add Custom Function Output to Python Logging Handler

Tags: python, logging, error-handling, formatting

Using `logging` to handle logging across multiple modules within a simulation framework with it's own 'time'.

Basically, I'm getting things like:

```
WARNING:Node[n0].App:RoutingTest:No Packet Count List set up yet; fudging it with an broadcast first
INFO:Node[n0].Layercake.ALOHA:Transmit to Any
INFO:Node[n0].Layercake.ALOHA:The timeout is 16.0910738255
WARNING:Node[n1].App:RoutingTest:No Packet Count List set up yet; fudging it with an broadcast first
INFO:Node[n1].Layercake.ALOHA:Transmit to Any
```

And while these happen more or less instantaneously in 'real' time it's tough to tell what that means in machine time.

Within the framework, there's a globally accessible `Sim.now()` that returns the current run time.

While I could go through all my logging uses and add this as an additional tail field, I'd rather add it as part of the base `logging` handler, however a scan through the relevant documentation and searches here and google haven't turned up anything directly relevant. There was one guy asking almost [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071309/best-way-to-add-custom-information-to-for-logging) but didn't get an appropriate response

In essence, I want to up date the base handler to prefix all log calls with a call to this function, effectively

```
logline="[{T}]:{msg}".format(T=Sim.now(), msg=logmsg)
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom [Formatter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#formatter-objects):

```
import logging
from sim import Sim

class SimNowPrefixFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        log_message = super(SimNowPrefixFormatter, self).format(record)
        return "[{}]:{}".format(Sim.now(), log_message)

# Your base logging handler
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(SimNowPrefixFormatter("%(levelname)s:%(message)s"))
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.addHandler(handler)
```